# Problem when saving a nested form in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In my app I have a view called profiles. On this view the user can update your albums and the photos of those albums.

A User has many Albums. And a Album has many Photos.

Im creating a form inside my profile view to save a album. Like this:

```
#routes.rb
  get '/profile/edit/profile_albums', to: 'profiles#edit_profile_albums'


#/view/profile/edit/profile_albums.html.erb


<%= form_for album do |f| %>
    <div class="dialog dialog-centered" id=<%= album.id %> style="display: block;">
      <div class="dialog-container dialog-wide">
        <div class="dialog-content panel">
          <div class="form-group bottom-7">
            <label for="">Album Name</label>
            <input type="text" id="" value=<%= album.name %> placeholder="Add Album Name">
          </div>
          <div class="edit-photo-album bottom-5">
          <% album.photos.each do |photo| %>
           <span class="edit-photo">
              <img src="<%= asset_path ix_refile_image_url(photo, :media, fit: 'fill', bg: '0fff') %>" class="photo-preview">
                <a href="" title="Remove" class="remove-item">Remove</a>
           </span>
          <% end %>
                <span class="btn btn-default btn-file">
                        <i ></i> Upload Photos 
                        <%= f.attachment_field :photos_media, multiple: true, direct: true, presigned: true %>
                    </span>

          </div><!-- end photo album -->
          <p>
          <div class="actions">
            <%= f.submit 'Save Album', class: 'btn btn-lg btn-solid-red btn-margin-right' %>
          </div>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-outline-green dialog-close">Cancel</button>
          </p>
        </div><!-- end dialog content -->
      </div><!-- end dialog container -->
    </div>
<% end %>
```

When I pressing the button save:

```
 <%= f.submit 'Save Album', class: 'btn btn-lg btn-solid-red btn-margin-right' %>
```

I get this message:

```
Routing Error
No route matches [PATCH] "/profile/edit/albums"
```

Someone can help me?

Thanks

Comment: Why do you need a URL like this: `'/profile/edit/profile_albums'`, and not `'/profile/:id/edit/profile_albums'`?

Answer (score 3):

I think you need to specify the `url` in the `form_for`.

First using `rake routes`, check for the route where this form should be sent to, and then modify your `form for` to be something like:

```
<%= form_for album, url: edit_profile_albums_path do |f| %>
```

Just replace `edit_profile_albums` with the path you will get when you run `rake routes`

Answer (score 1):

As the error suggests, you need to add the proper route for the form to work. In this case, it's probably `resources :albums` in `routes.rb`. I recommend going through this guide (easy to read): https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html